# Partial View - How to get the Id of button from a list of partial views in mvc and how to invoke same action by passing there id's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a multiple partials views on main view with specific employee name and button to get full data for that employee. I am not getting any idea of how to invoke specific action to display data in pop-up and get the full data of that specific  employee on button click.

Comment: Add the id of the employee to the data, that is being posted to the server. Or do you want to open a popup without going to the server first?

Comment: I want to call another action method by passing id to that method. But How it identify which employee details it want to display from a list of partial view?

Comment: Do you have a table with all employees and want to click a row to show data? How does your page look? Share the html please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the model for each partial view includes the employee's ID, you could use anchor tags instead of buttons and include the employee ID in the href attribute.

For example, in your partial view for the employee details, include something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Employee", new { id: Model.EmployeeID })">Details...</a>
```

If you decide to use javascript instead to display the popup, check out data attributes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

In that case, you could render a button like this in your Partial View:

```
<button type="button" class="employee-btn" data-employee-id="@Model.EmployeeID">Details...</button>
```

And then read the value in javascript (this example uses jQuery event handlers):

```
$('.employee-btn').click(function() {
    var employeeId = $(this).data('employee-id');
    // logic to fetch employee details and display in popup...
});
```